# HTML double left quote, htmlentities

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

Hi I am having trouble with a certain character in PHP. the character is “ which should return

```
&ldquo;
```

but when I do

```
echo htmlentities('“');
```

I get

```
&acirc;��
```

What Am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your file is in utf-8 and version of php is less than 5.4 so tell htmlentities this.

```
echo htmlentities('“', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: just realized my PHP version. I thought it would be the latest one as I get it from the centos repository

Answer (score 0):

Try using online interpreter like this one [codeonline](http://writecodeonline.com/php/).

It returned the quote (") without an issue in my case. For further documentation, check documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

(FYI, more sandbox tools can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616159/is-there-a-php-sandbox-something-like-jsfiddle-is-to-js)).