# HTML class names with php variables

Tags: php, html

I have a massive page but I have recconstructed the error in a JS FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/qsJ5R/

```
<li><input class="<?php echo $env;?>" type="checkbox" > This is Item 1</li>
```

This is the line that has the error.

It is not reading the class name as what the variable is equal too?

am i missing something or can you not do this ?

Comment: close it `<?php $env = "env"; ?>`

Comment: Have you copied and pasted your code into the JSFiddle? Because you're not closing your first PHP tag.

Comment: JSFiddle can't run PHP. [Similar topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616159/is-there-a-php-sandbox-something-like-jsfiddle-is-to-js)

Comment: Did you actually get any PHP fatal error?

Comment: no i get nothing and yes i have corrected the copy and paste issue now

Comment: have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qsJ5R/8/ I assume that is what you are trying to do

Comment: yes but that class obviously has to be dynamic thats why its a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML as

```
<body>
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
<?php $env = "env" ?>
        <ul class="chk-container">
           <li><input class="selecctall" type="checkbox"> Selecct All</li>
           <li><input class="<?php echo $env;?>" type="checkbox" > This is Item 1</li>
           <li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" > This is Item 2</li>
           <li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" > This is Item 3</li>
           <li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" > This is Item 4</li>
           <li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" > This is Item 5</li>
           <li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" > This is Item 6</li>
           <li><input class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" > Do not select this</li>

        </ul>
</body>
```

The problem is that, you are not closing the php tag

Comment: sorry that was just a copy and paste issue thats not the actual problem sorry

Comment: check this part <?php $env = "env" ?>. Any difference ?