# Implementing PHP Inside a HTML Table

Tags: php, html-table

Currently, I am building a table full of content. I can sucessfuly make one row that has one cell (the first cell) saying data, however when I attempt to use php to echo something, it does not show up. Why is this?
If you need my whole program I would be happy to include it, however to stay clean I am going to only include a section of the table.

Code:

```
   <tr>
    <td>data </td>
    <td><?php echo "hi"; ?> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hope as per your code nothing wrong.... can u post full code ?

Comment: Make sure your page ends with the extension `.php`

Comment: Do you have an apache webserver running?

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5aZn2/

Comment: I cannot echo the text inside the table. I am using the WAMP server and yes I confirmed it is online and since the other parts of the website work, the server must be working fine.

Comment: it generates: `<!--?php echo "hi"; ?-->`, but maybe it's just how jsfiddle works..

Comment: No, thats whats weird it doesn't generate anything

Comment: As far as i am aware, JSFiddle does not support PHP

Comment: Please refer something from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616159/is-there-a-php-sandbox-something-like-jsfiddle-is-to-js

Comment: I am not using Jfiddle, I just used this to show the code.

Comment: Oh ok... Are u sure you are running PHP correctly?

Comment: try <?php phpinfo(); ?> if it doesn't show you your phpinfo table, then it seems your php is not setup correctly.

Comment: @user3496349 : u sure u running your page from `wamp` ( *windows* ) or `lamp` ( *lamp* ) with page extension `.php`

Comment: Yes Im sure I am using the WAMP server

Comment: @user3496349 : then post complete code with file name! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is very right.
There are two reasons why that may not be working. 
1- check if  your filename ends with .php
and 
2- check if you are running your code from a webserver that supports php.

To know if php is installed just try to right a simple php page iwth the following content.

if it renders it means you  have php installed