# PHP - SandBox for an Interactive Course

Tags: javascript, php, sandbox, read-eval-print-loop

I have a personal project of building a PHP sandbox in order to build a PHP interactive course. I want to to achieve something like [Codeshcool](https://www.codeschool.com/)'s [Ruby](http://tryruby.org/), [JavaScript](http://javascript-roadtrip.codeschool.com/) and [Git](https://try.github.io/) courses or [Codeacademy's PHP course](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php) in the sense of having a PHP REPL and terminal where you can run PHP statements and scripts, respectively.

The main goal is building a tool for people new to PHP and of course share it with the world which would make it a win-win project.

What technology would serve me best? Is there some library I can use for building the REPL/terminal? I was thinking JavaScript so I can embed this to the browser, maybe passing commands to the PHP interpreter from JavaScript code but I don't know if this is nonsense.

Comment: Have a look at [Runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php) for the server-side

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616159/is-there-a-php-sandbox-something-like-jsfiddle-is-to-js?rq=1

Comment: Seems to me that php-console is the way to go, but how can I get something like [psysh](http://psysh.org/) to work from the browser?

Comment: did you check boris (A tiny, but robust REPL for PHP)?? https://packagist.org/packages/d11wtq/boris