# PHP Try it yourself interpreter

Tags: php, html

I want to design a php try it yourself interpreter like we have in w3schools.com for CSS and JS. I googled plenty of stuff i could not find something helpful.
What i have tried so far is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
</div>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
<input type="submit">

<textarea name="code"><?= htmlentities($_POST["code"]) ?></textarea>

<div id="output">
  <?= $_POST["code"] ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have taken this code from on of the websites on web and honestly speaking its a part of my assignment, i just need some guidance.

Comment: its not clear, what do you want?

Comment: Sandboxes for PHP already exist. Use one of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616159/is-there-a-php-sandbox-something-like-jsfiddle-is-to-js/4616435#4616435

Comment: I think it is already awesome the way it is. Just add a couple adSense blocks and start making money.

Comment: Please make your question clear.

Comment: what i want is to allow the user to enter any php code and show its output.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use ***PHP Console***

You can clone or download the ZIP file from official [GitHub Page](https://github.com/seldaek/php-console), and navigate to the path where you have installed via your browser.

Note: You need some tweaking if you want to use it online(on your website etc..)

[Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616159/is-there-a-php-sandbox-something-like-jsfiddle-is-to-js/4616435#4616435)

Hope this helps. :)