# HTML inside of PHP variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am still very new to MySQL/PHP and am trying to make code that will loop through my whole SQL table.  I was able to do that, to clean things up I wanted to use an html table to store the values in to make things look neater.  I tried adding the HTML code into the string which gets printed at the bottom of the code in the HTML section, but the table borders do not show.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?  Both code and screenshot of output are below:

```
<?php

    include("connection.php");

    $query= "SELECT * FROM schedule";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $scheduletext="<table>";

    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $scheduletext="<tr><td>".$scheduletext.$row[1]."</td>";

            $scheduletext="<td>".$scheduletext.$row[2]."</td>";

            $scheduletext="<td>".$scheduletext.$row[3]."</td>";

            $scheduletext="<td>".$scheduletext.$row[4]."</td></tr>";

        }
    }
    $scheduletext=$scheduletext."</table>";

?>

<html>
    <head>

        <title>TastySnack - Production Schedule</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">       

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tasty.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="top">

            <div id="top-left">

                TastySnack Production

            </div>

            <div id="top-right">

                <img id="logo" src="images/TastysnackLogo.jpg">

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="split"></div>

        <div id="schedule">

            <?php 

                print_r($scheduletext);

            ?>  

        </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

[Click Here For Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9drgn.png)

Comment: use concatenation: `$scheduletext .=` (notice the dot)

Comment: Look at your source code an you should see the issue. `<tr><td><table>` is not going to be right.

Comment: @chris85 I see what you are saying!  Why is it adding all the extras at the beginning though?

<td><td><td><tr><td><td><td><td><tr><td><td><td><td><tr><td><td><td><td><tr><td><td><td><td><tr><td><td><td><td><tr><td><td><td><td><tr><td><td><td><td><tr><td><table>0000-00-00</td>22oz Dark</td>12ct 4oz Dark</td></td></tr>2016-01-01</td>9785</td>2478</td></td></tr>2016-01-02</td>8754</td>2136</td></td></tr>2016-01-03</td>.........

Comment: Because you are adding `<td>` to the start of the variable on every iteration. Simple example, https://eval.in/663332, then multiple that by how many rows your have. Extended example: https://eval.in/663337

Comment: I am not familiar with eval.in, im assuming it is like jsbin?  to be honest I dont fully understand my code, I am still learning, played around with it and it seemed to work for outputting the MySQL table.

Comment: Yup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616159/is-there-a-php-sandbox-something-like-jsfiddle-is-to-js.

Answer (score 0):

As @mister martin said in comment use dot to concatinate your string

```
$scheduletext ="<table>";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $scheduletext .="<tr><td>".$scheduletext.$row[1]."</td>";

        $scheduletext .="<td>".$scheduletext.$row[2]."</td>";

        $scheduletext .="<td>".$scheduletext.$row[3]."</td>";

        $scheduletext .="<td>".$scheduletext.$row[4]."</td></tr>";

    }
}
$scheduletext .="</table>";
```

Comment: Don't concatenate `$scheduletext`.

Comment: That did not work for me.  I got the fatal error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 116497061 bytes) in /home2/bweibley/public_html/www.kr3ativedesign.com/GnS/Index.php on line 19

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096582/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted