# PHP function: Can it return a global variable while simultaneously assigning a value to it?

Tags: php, function, return, global-variables

I have the next code inside PHP function:

```
$_SESSION['verified'] = true;
return true;
```

Can I replace it with:

```
return $_SESSION['verified'] = true;
```

If yes, will the value be assigned to `$_SESSION['verified']` after function is terminated?

Comment: Yes, yes you can. your two lines of code are the same result. The assignment will happen then the return.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Nope - researching theory atm and don't have environment set up. I searched on Google and here though before posting it first.

Comment: Well, as Scuzzy already said: Yes, this will work. It's how expressions are evaluated, the return will be the last thing.

Comment: @Scuzzy perfect thanks, couldn't find anything on assignment while returning.

Comment: In these cases it's easier to simply try, than to study documentation.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware hey, we've just created the documentation with this post together so its all good ;)

Comment: In the future if you search for `PHP Sandbox` you can use one of the online environments. I usually use https://3v4l.org/ but there are a few options. This thread is useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616159/is-there-a-php-sandbox-something-like-jsfiddle-is-to-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, when you use an assignment expression like $_SESSION['verified'] = true, the value of true is assigned to the $_SESSION['verified'] variable, and the expression also evaluates to that value (true). By using the expression return $_SESSION['verified'] = true;, you are both assigning true to $_SESSION['verified'] and returning that same value. I hope this part make sence, Then because the assignment expression is evaluated first, $_SESSION['verified'] will be assigned the value true before the return statement is executed. Therefore, the value of $_SESSION['verified'] will also be true when the function returns true.

In summary, you can replace $_SESSION['verified'] = true; return true; with return $_SESSION['verified'] = true; to achieve the same result with less code, and the value of $_SESSION['verified'] will still be assigned as true before the function returns.